# To forever come around

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

One for hunt and silver hue.
One for war and battles due.
One for trade and souls askew.
One for sky and thunder too.
One for love and beauty true.
One for peace and fortune through.
One for light and warmth anew.

All quite clever have been bound
By this lever so renowned
To forever come around.

Comment: One to rule them all and in the darkness bind them...

Comment: I guess my French killer was your inspiration? ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I hope everyone else noticed the number. This refers to

> the days of the week.

One for hunt and silver hue.

> Refers to the moon, for Monday.

One for war and battles due.

> Mars is the god of War, as well as the origin of Tuesday.

One for trade and souls askew.

> Wodan was known to guide souls after death. Hence, Wednesday.

One for sky and thunder too.

> Thursday is Thor's Day.

One for love and beauty true.

> Freya was the Norse goddess of love and beauty. Friday.

One for peace and fortune through.

> Saturn was the herald of the age of prosperity. Saturday.

One for light and warmth anew.

> The sun. Sunday.

All quite clever have been bound
By this lever so renowned
To forever come around.

> Not sure what this lever is, but they are forever bound to the calendar.

Comment: Amazingly accurate.